# Flashing Table Row

Tags: javascript

I have a dynamic table, and set conditions to make the table row background color changed based on time comparison. I want to add a second logic that will make the table row flash/blink every 2 seconds if cells are not matching. I understand that I need to create the "Flash/Blink" function but how do I integrate that function into my logic below?

```
for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    cells = rows[i].getElementsByTagName('td');
    if (cells[10].innerText != cells[11].innterText) {
        rows[i].className = "blink/Flash";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Look ma, no JavaScript!

### HTML

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>true</td>
        <td class="invalid">false</td>
        <td>true</td>
        <td>true</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

### CSS

```
@-webkit-keyframes invalid {
  from { background-color: red; }
  to { background-color: inherit; }
}
@-moz-keyframes invalid {
  from { background-color: red; }
  to { background-color: inherit; }
}
@-o-keyframes invalid {
  from { background-color: red; }
  to { background-color: inherit; }
}
@keyframes invalid {
  from { background-color: red; }
  to { background-color: inherit; }
}
.invalid {
  -webkit-animation: invalid 1s infinite; /* Safari 4+ */
  -moz-animation:    invalid 1s infinite; /* Fx 5+ */
  -o-animation:      invalid 1s infinite; /* Opera 12+ */
  animation:         invalid 1s infinite; /* IE 10+ */
}
```

### Live demo

http://jsfiddle.net/bikeshedder/essxz/

---

## For those poor souls who are forced to use an outdated browser

### CSS

```
.invalid-blink {
    background-color: red;
}
```

### JavaScript

```
$(function() {
    var on = false;
    window.setInterval(function() {
        on = !on;
        if (on) {
            $('.invalid').addClass('invalid-blink')
        } else {
            $('.invalid-blink').removeClass('invalid-blink')
        }
    }, 2000);
});
```

### Live demo

http://jsfiddle.net/bikeshedder/SMwAn/

Comment: This a great tool but unfortunately it does not work on IE 6/7+ which is what I need.

Comment: I added another example which somewhat emulates the original CSS. It is really simple and does not cache the list of elements. If your page grows very large it will be ineffective and you should cache the JQuery selectors.

Comment: lol yes Im forced to develop with old IE versions, but thank you very much!

Comment: how can I call this function into my row styling...I current want to place it here    rows[i].styleclassName = "function"

Comment: You just need to add the class `invalid` to that row. What this code does is simpleE Every 2 seconds, either add the class `invalid-blink` to all elements with an `invalid` class or remove the class `invalid-blink` from all elements. I you add the `invalid` class to the row you need to modify the CSS slightly: `.invalid-blink td { background-color: red }`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<style type="text/css">
   /* styles to make cells red when under row with class "blink" */
   tr.blink td {background-color:#ff0000;}
</style>

var blinking_rows = []; //array to store rows that must blink

if (cells[10].innerText != cells[11].innterText) 
{
   rows[i].className = "blink"; //this makes cells background color red
   blinking_rows[blinking_rows.length] = rows[i]; //saving row DOM object into array
}

//Running a timer that makes the row blinks every 2 seconds by changing their class
window.setInterval(function() 
{
   for(var i = 0, len = blinking_rows.length; i < len; ++i)
      if(blinking_rows[i].className === "blink") //I'm supposing you do not add other classes
         blinking_rows[i].className = ""; //removing class, this makes the row not red anymore
      else
         blinking_rows[i].className = "blink"; //this makes the row red again
}, 2000);
```