# Blink cell on data change AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

so I'm new to Angular and JS and I've been trying to do something simple with no success.

I have a table with data, everytime this data gets changed I want to make a fade in fade out animation so it blinks. I assumed I could use `$watch` to watch if an element changes but it's not working.

This is what I got so far:

**HTML:**

```
<tbody md-body>
   <tr md-row ng-repeat="item in info.data">
      <td md-cell>{{item.name}}</td>
      <td md-cell>{{item.id}}</td>
      <td md-cell>{{item.thing2}}</td>
      <td md-cell>{{item.thing3}}</td>
      <td md-cell>{{item.thing4}}</td>
      <td md-cell>{{item.thing5}}</td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
```

**JS:**

```
 $scope.info = {
  "data": [
    {
      name: "ELI 0001",
      id: "123",
      thing1: "thing",
      thing2: "thing",
      thing3: "thing",
      thing4: "thing",
      thing5:"thing",
    },
    {
      name: "ELI 0001",
      id: "123",
      thing1: "thing",
      thing2: "thing",
      thing3: "thing",
      thing4: "thing",
      thing5:"thing",
    },
  ]
};
```

I added this function to watch the entire data set for changes, and when it does I made an alert. I also added the var `initialising` so it doesn't show up as soon as it loads.

```
var initializing = true
$scope.$watch('if',function(){
  if (initializing) {
    $timeout(function() { initializing = false; });
  } else {
    alert('hey')
  }
})
```

My problem is, how can I get it to watch all cells and execute a class that does the animation only on the data that changed?

Comment: Add event listeners to each cell of your table and have it fire on the individual cell.

Comment: how will data be changed ?

Comment: I'm simulating with button click right now

Answer (score 1):

AS this thread https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/angular/xZptsb-NYc4/rKAxJ3dQhbMJ, what I ended up doing was this:

```
app.directive('highlightOnChange', function() {
  return {
    link: function($scope, element, attrs) {
      attrs.$observe('highlightOnChange', function(val) {
        var el = $(element);
        el.removeClass('blink_me ');
        _.defer(function() {
          el.addClass('blink_me ')
        });
      });
    }
  };
});
```

That is, creating a directive observes the property. You can then use it like this:

```
<td md-cell highlight-on-change="{{item.name}}"></td>
...
```

suppose your css class be:

```
.blink_me {
  animation: blinker 1s linear infinite;
}    
@keyframes blinker {
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was working on a similar approach to @khateeb -- except I am using a `$watch` on the element's `ng-model` instead of using `$observe` on the directive attribute. Both work!

Plunker: https://embed.plnkr.co/rZVjPmDft997Kmny1LS4/

Snippet:

```js
(function() {

  "use strict";

  var app = angular
    .module('plunker', [])
    .controller('MainCtrl', MainCtrl)
    .directive('flashTd', flashTD);

  function flashTD($timeout, $compile) {
    return {
      scope: {
        ngModel: '='
      },
      link: function($scope, elem, attrs) {

        // Set a watch on ng-model to wait for value change
        $scope.$watch('ngModel', function(newVal, oldVal) {
          if (newVal !== oldVal) {
            // Flash row
            // var row = angular.element(elem[0].parentNode.parentNode);

            // Flash td
            var td = angular.element(elem[0].parentNode);

            // Using a timeout to simulate remote data change
            $timeout(function() {

              if (td.hasClass('flash')) {
                td.removeClass('flash');
              }

              $timeout(function() {
                td.addClass('flash')
              })

            }, 2000)

          }
        })
      }
    }
  }

  MainCtrl.$inject = ["$scope"];

  function MainCtrl($scope) {

    // Sample Data
    $scope.info = {
      "data": [{
        name: "ELI 0001",
        id: "123",
        thing1: "thing",
        thing2: "thing",
        thing3: "thing",
        thing4: "thing",
        thing5: "thing",
      }, {
        name: "ELI 0001",
        id: "1234",
        thing1: "thing",
        thing2: "thing",
        thing3: "thing",
        thing4: "thing",
        thing5: "thing",
      }]
    };

  }

})()
```

```css
.editPencil:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14607695/flashing-table-row */

@keyframes flash {
  from {
    background-color: #ffbe76;
  }
  to {
    background-color: inherit;
  }
}

.flash {
  animation: flash 1s 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS - Flash TD on Change</title>
  <link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.7" data-semver="3.3.7" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="bootstrap@3.3.7" data-semver="3.3.7" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>

  <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.20/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.20"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="jumbotron text-center">
          <h3>AngularJS - Flash TD on Change</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
        <form class="form">
          <div class="form-group">
            <table class="table">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th></th>
                  <th>Name</th>
                  <th>Id</th>
                  <th>Thing1</th>
                  <th>Thing2</th>
                  <th>Thing3</th>
                  <th>Thing4</th>
                  <th>Thing5</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="item in info.data">
                  <td class="editPencil glyphicon-pencil text-center" style="transform: rotate(45deg)" ng-click="editRow = !editRow"></td>
                  <td>
                    <span ng-hide="editRow">{{ item.name }}</span>
                    <input type="text" class="input-sm" ng-model="item.name" ng-hide="!editRow" flash-td />
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <span ng-hide="editRow">{{ item.id }}</span>
                    <input type="text" class="input-sm" ng-model="item.id" ng-hide="!editRow" flash-td />
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <span ng-hide="editRow">{{ item.thing1 }}</span>
                    <input type="text" class="input-sm" ng-model="item.thing1" ng-hide="!editRow" flash-td />
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <span ng-hide="editRow">{{ item.thing2 }}</span>
                    <input type="text" class="input-sm" ng-model="item.thing2" ng-hide="!editRow" flash-td />
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <span ng-hide="editRow">{{ item.thing3 }}</span>
                    <input type="text" class="input-sm" ng-model="item.thing3" ng-hide="!editRow" flash-td />
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <span ng-hide="editRow">{{ item.thing4 }}</span>
                    <input type="text" class="input-sm" ng-model="item.thing4" ng-hide="!editRow" flash-td />
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <span ng-hide="editRow">{{ item.thing5 }}</span>
                    <input type="text" class="input-sm" ng-model="item.thing5" ng-hide="!editRow" flash-td />
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

### Directive

In my demo, I'm flashing the `td`, but you can as easily change it to flash the target's table row by using the commented-out `row` variable instead of the `td` variable.

```
app.directive('flashTd', flashTD);

function flashTD($timeout, $compile) {
    return {
      scope: {
        ngModel: '='
      },
      link: function($scope, elem, attrs) {

        // Set a watch on ng-model to wait for value change
        $scope.$watch('ngModel', function(newVal, oldVal) {
          if (newVal !== oldVal) {
            // Flash row
            // var row = angular.element(elem[0].parentNode.parentNode);

            // Flash td
            var td = angular.element(elem[0].parentNode);

            // Using a timeout to simulate remote data change
            $timeout(function() {

              if(td.hasClass('flash')) {
                td.removeClass('flash');
              }

              $timeout(function() {
                td.addClass('flash')
              })

            }, 2000)

           }
        })
      }
    }
  }
```

### HTML Element

```
 <input type="text" class="input-sm" ng-model="item.thing2" ng-hide="!editRow" flash-td />
```